# Cant use SendKeys but can Click on a web element (textbox)

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver

There is a textbox on a webpage where I can click() and it works but if i do sendkeys, I get element not intractable error. I am trying to write automation test script

My test code:

```
    IWebElement text1 =                 
    driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@id='mainForm:OT_j_id788']"));
    text1.Click();
    //text1.Clear();
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    text1.SendKeys("Test001");
```

I have tried inserting clear(), even tried java script executer - not working got no errors

```
    IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
    //jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", text1);
```

HTML Structure:

```
<table id="mainForm:OT_j_id776"..>
 <tr id="mainForm:OT_j_id785"..>
  <td id="mainForm:OT_j_id788"..>
   <span id="mainForm:OT_j_id789C"..>
   </span>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Add relevant `HTML` source

Comment: @Fenio I added the code..please let me know if you need more details

Comment: Try to `sendKeys` to `span` element instead of `td`